# Retrieving data from webview in Windows 8.1 Store HTML5 app

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows Store HTML5/Javascript app.  As part of my app I need to invoke a Javascript method on a web page and retrieve its return value.

The control `x-ms-webview` has a method `invokeScriptAsync` that can invoke a script on a webview.  However there is no way of retrieving a value back from any method call.

It also does not seem to support the standard method of communication with a host app, `window.external.notify`.

How can I retrieve a value from a web page in a Windows Store app webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIGHT.

Starting to make a bit more sense.  The code I mentioned in the comments:

```
var async = webview.invokeScriptAsync('eval', '(function() { return 1337 })()')
async.oncomplete = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.result)
}
async.start()
```

logs null.

However replacing the number `1337` with the string `'1337'` logs the expected value.

Still no luck with doing `window.external.notify` -- but at least some form of dialogue with the webview is possible.

---

EDIT `window.external.notify` **does** work, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735533/64505) originally had the wrong event to listen for, but it is now correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can get return values from an invoked script, but you have to add an oncomplete handler to the object returned from invokeScriptAsync. For example, take scenario 5 of the [HTML Webview control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-WebView-control-sample-56e773fa) and modify the code in 5_InvokeScript.js as follows:

```
function invokeScript() {
    var op = document.getElementById("webview").invokeScriptAsync("changeText", document.getElementById("textInput").value);

    op.oncomplete = function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.result);
    };

    op.start();
}
```

And then in script_example.html, change the function to this:

```
function changeText(text) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = text;
    return text;
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the console.log call in the app and you'll see that e.target.result contains the return value.

`window.external.notify` does also work, raising the `MSWebViewScriptNotify` event from the Webview. Note that `MSWebViewScriptNotify` will be raised only from webviews loaded with ms-appx-web, ms-local-stream, and https content, where https also requires a content URI rule in your manifest, otherwise that event will be blocked. ms-appdata is also allowed if you have a URI resolver involved. A webview loaded through navigateToString does not have this requirement.

Comment: 1)  I load an empty page (`<html>Hi</html>`) using `navigateToString`, then on `MSWebViewNavigationCompleted` I do `var async = webview.invokeScriptAsync('eval', '(function() { return 1337 })()');`.  `async`'s `oncomplete` gets invoked, but `e.target.result` is `null` -- I would expect 1337.

Comment: 2)  I then navigate to an `https` page within the same webview.  This page attempts to do `window.external.notify`.  If I do not add the page's URI to my manifest, I get a warning that an unapproved page is attempting to do `external.notify`.  Great!  I then add the URI to my manifest and listen for `MSWebviewScriptNotify`, and nothing.  The event is not invoked and the warning no longer appears.

Comment: As you are from MS I may as well comment that documentation about `external.notify` is very hard to find, it is not mentioned at all in this description of `x-ms-webview` :: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx :: and Googling for `MSWebviewScriptNotify` returns only six results (including this page!)

Comment: I agree. I file lots of bugs on the docs and will include this when I submit my next round. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: RIGHT.  `window.external.notify` **does** work; you have to listen for `MSWebViewScriptNotify` -- **not** `MSWebviewScriptNotify` as the answer originally said!  I have edited it appropriately.