# UWP WebView calls dynamic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, win-universal-app

I have studied Window Universal App these days.  When working with WebView, I see it can invoke a script inside the html file, but how about executing an external JavaScript script?

```
WebView webview = new WebView();
webview.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
string script = @"
   function getBodyHTML()
   {
       var innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
       return innerHTML;
   }
";
```

I want to get the bodyHTML, possibly using something like this:

```
// pseudo code
webview.IncludeScript(script);
string bodyHTML = webview.ExecuteScript("getBodyHTML()");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving data from webview in Windows 8.1 Store HTML5 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734973/retrieving-data-from-webview-in-windows-8-1-store-html5-app)

Answer (score 0):

oops, just realize that the similar question was answered.

I could do my thing by:

```
string[] arguments = new string[] {@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;"};

try
 {
   string bodyHTML = await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", arguments);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```